# Nexus proxy server

Tags: proxy, java, python

I have installed and configured Sonatype Nexus server as caching Proxy for Java(maven central) and Python(PyPi).
It is working fine.
Also i have some "internal" hosted repositories for Java and Python software that is written inside our team.
I don't want to publish this software to public.
Do i need some extra configurations on Proxy, to prevent developers from pushing to maven central and PyPi?
Or i need to change

- OS: Centos 7 latest
- Nexus: 3.12
- User authentication on Nexus:
  Active Directory for hosted repositories.
  Anonymous access to proxy repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot publish to a proxy repository through NXRM for any format.**

After that, who can access what in NXRM is defined by Security permissions.  You can read more [here](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Security).

Specifically, it sounds like you'd want to restrict your anonymous (public) access to the hosted repositories.  By default it shows all, however, you can adjust this by adjusting what the anonymous role can access.

You may want to adjust other user permissions as well.

There's no way to prevent anyone with access to these repositories from downloading hosted data and uploading it somewhere else.  So it sounds like you have a bit of a trust exercise.

Comment: I have understand the part with `nx-anonymous` user in Nexus. I have a little bit other question. I'm asking if i need to implement some extra rules in Nexus to disable possibility to publish artifacts thought `maven-proxy` to `maven-central`. Or it is disabled by default.

Comment: @UNIm95 You can't publish to any proxy repository in any NXRM version.  Hope that helps.